# Access frontend and backend simultaneously locked by user

Tags: ms-access, frontend, backend

In our company, we created a small Access database, which was in a network folder for everyone to access it.
After a while we decided to split it into a backend and a frontend. The new frontend is at the same location the original data was while the original data, serving as the backend now, is in a subfolder of the folder it used to be located in, so all relevant data is accessible to the the employees as it has always been.
The current problem is, that today, most of the time both the BE and the FE have their ".Iaccdb" files showing up and if you try to open any of the two, BE or FE, it will say, that a user is using the database in the exclusive mode.
I guess solving the problem at hand isn't the main issue here. What I rather like to know is, WHAT must have happened, to cause both files to behave this way.
I heard about this happening to either the BE or the FE, but never both simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Never use a shared frontend:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html?preview=X8LitkMCd/Y%3D).

Comment: There's also a known bug with Windows server having to do with file leases that cause the backend databases to be locked and report as corrupt.

Comment: @Duston: That's another situation: [Database is in an Unrecognized Format](https://www.devhut.net/2018/06/13/access-bug-database-is-in-an-unrecognized-format/).

Answer (score 0):

I found out what caused the issue and in doing so also have to apologize for omiting one relevant detail: The old file I started with also had **connections to Sharepoint lists**.

Because of that, I couldnt just use the split function as it doesn't work if you're database is connected to Sharepoint.

So my workaround was to copy the access file in the upper folder as the new FrontEnd. In this new file/FE, i just created links to the old file's table, which now serves as the backEnd.

As I said, there were connections in the old file/BE.
When I first tried the FE, it worked properly. only when someone already opened the FE and another one wanted to do the same, the issue of users blocking each other appeared.

My solution was to get rid of the SharePoint connections in the old file/BE and now everything works smoothly.